# problems with UTF-8-BOM in R on different Windows systems

Tags: r, windows, utf

I am struggling at the moment with the `UTF-8-BOM` under one windows system and I am not sure if the problem is related to R, the operating system or something else.

**System A** win10; R 4.2.2

**System B** win server 2019; R 4.3.2

I am using a software which creates tab separated txt files which I always opened via `read.delim('filename.txt')` without problems.
Now, on the System B, the first column name is different and looks like `ï..Parameter` and all my scripts are no longer running. I figured out, that this is supposed to be the `UTF-8-BOM` and by reading the file with `read.delim('filename.txt', fileEncoding='UTF-8-BOM')` everything works as normal and the first column name is `Parameter` as expected.

The funny thing is, on System A, everything works normal and I can use all my scripts as usual. Even if I open the files on System B via network drive.

Can I get some advice, if this is related to operating system, general system settings or how I can figure out what the exact issue on System B is, why I now have to use that `UTF-8-BOM` parameter, but on the other system it is fine.

Comment: Can you check `Sys.getenv()` on both systems for differences in LANG and LC settings (starts about line 22 of the output)?

Comment: @jay.sf thanks for your feedback. There are no such variables on both windows system. On my Mac, where I also have NO problems, LANG and LC_CTYPE are set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Ok, thought maybe setting correct locales might help. But no clue how doing this in Windows, since I quit using it.